# Qual a diferença entre "Issues" e "Pull Requests"?

Tags: github

Em um repositório do GitHub, qual a diferença entre a seção "Issues" e "Pull Requests"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Issue** é passivo, você diz que tem um problema naquele projeto que você achou e gostaria que fosse tratado, por alguém, pode até ser tratado por você mesmo, é uma marcação que o problema existe. É algo burocrático (no bom sentido) e complementar ao projeto em si.

O **Pull Request** é ativo, ele é uma solicitação para incluir no projeto uma modificação que você fez, o que pode eventualmente ter iniciado através de um Issue. E por organização seria bom que fosse sempre assim, mas não precisa. Ele é parte do projeto, tem consequência real.

Ambos poderão ser considerados válidos pela administração ou comunidade do projeto. O Issue é fácil ser fechado ou abandonado, com ou sem justificativa. A recusa do PR sempre desperdiçará uma atividade de alguém que se importou e se esforçou em contribuir.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Um ponto curioso. De forma técnica, no GitHub, as issues e os pull requests são a mesma entidade, porém cada uma tem suas particularidades. Eles dividem muita coisa. Tanto é que eles seguem a mesma numeração, não tem uma separada para cada um. Quanto você clica na seção Issues do GitHub, ele aparece na barra de busca `is:issue`. O mesmo acontece para Pull Requests, porém como `is:pr`. As máquinas de estado parecem ser as mesmas, e os filtros disponíveis também.

Comment: @vnbrs Faz sentido, o PR é um *issue*, com especificidades.

Answer (score 6):

**Issues**, do inglês **problemas**, é a seção onde os usuários relatam bugs e onde a comunidade discute como resolvê-los.

**Pull Request** é quando você clona o projeto, faz algumas melhorias e quer submetê-las ao projeto original, então você faz um pull Request. O pull request pode ser corrigindo um bug que já foi reportado nas **Issues** ou não.

Essa foi uma resposta bem resumida. Para algo bem completo, com tutorial e imagens, [clique aqui](https://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/02/04/git-e-github-do-clone-ao-pull-request/)

Comment: Obrigado! Eu só não escolhi sua resposta pois a outra estava mais desenvolvida, muito obrigado.

Comment: Sem problemas amigo. A comunidade está aí para ajudar. Pontos são coisa secundária. Grande abraço

Comment: Uma Issue não é necessariamente é um problema. Pode ser um questionamento/assunto mesmo no contexto do github.