# Milestones e Projects no Github

Tags: github

Estou utilizando o github para meus projetos pessoais.

Uma das coisas que mais gosto é que ele possui várias ferramentas pra me auxiliar, não só no controle do fonte mas também do que foi feito.

Uma das opções interessantes são as issues. Elas são pendencias do projeto que podem ser abertas pelo dono do repositório ou por qualquer membro do github.

Elas possuem algumas opções de categoria.

#### Dúvida

Qual a diferença entre as `Milestones` (Aba `Issue`) e `Project` (Aba `Projects`)?

Ambas funcionam muito bem para controlar o progresso, mas queria saber qual a utilidade da `Milestone` em um projeto com `projects` configurado.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/345326/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os conceitos de *issues* e *projects* não são concorrentes e sim colaborativos. Os conceitos, segundo a ajuda do Github, são:

1. *Issue*: Utilize para acompanhar ideias, melhorias, tarefas ou bugs. (fonte: https://help.github.com/articles/about-issues/)

Ou seja, é a sua menor unidade de registro de trabalho, se você precisa implementar uma melhoria, corrigir um bug cria como *issue*.

Por exemplo, abaixo eu criei um *issue* reportando um erro que deve ser corrigido, mas reparece que já nessa tela existe o campo *Project* (1).

[image: Após criado um *issue* é possível adicioná-lo a um projeto]

Já o conceito de *project* dentro do Github é:

2. Você pode criar *project boards* para o desenvolvimento de uma *feature* específica, criar um *roadmap*, ou o que irá em uma determinada *release* checklists (fonte: https://help.github.com/articles/about-project-boards/)

Basicamente é um controle de projetos, e quando eu crio um, eu posso adicionar *issues* nele, por exemplo, o que eu criei no item anterior:

[image: Após criação de um novo projeto, a aba lateral direita permite a adição de *issues* existentes]

E por último:

3. Milestone agrega também vários *issues*, e com isso é possível setar como metas (fonte: https://help.github.com/articles/about-milestones/)

Abaixo eu coloquei um *issue* tanto em um projeto, como em um milestone:

[image: A *issue* é categorizada tanto no *milestone* 1.0.0 como no *project* Melhorias da aplicação para versão 2]

A ideia é: os usuários do repositório, registram problemas ou sugestões em *issues*, os administradores do repositório vão classificar se faz sentido, e podem incluí-lo em um projeto no futuro. O *project* por definição tem início, meio e fim; então ao criá-lo você determina quais itens de trabalho vão entrar no projeto, ou pode acrescentar ao longo do tempo; quando o projeto tiver o seu objetivo concluído, ele termina. No final você tem uma *release* entregável, e esta pode ser representada por um *milestone*, no caso dos exemplos acima com o nome 1.0.0.

Comment: Boa noite egomesbrandao. Consegui entender, era como eu imaginava.
Tanto as _milestones_ quanto os _projects_ servem para agrupar as _issues_, porém o foco do agrupamento para as entregas se encaixa melhor para as _milestones_.
Os _projects_ ficariam à critério de quem tivesse gerenciando o projeto, podendo separar tanto por funcionalidade quanto pela própria entrega, dependendo do que se encaixasse melhor. Me corrija, por favor, se eu estiver errado.
Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Acho que pode ser da maneira que você colocou. Entenda que isso é um agrupamento lógico, vale mais o sentido que você der e se estiver trazendo benefício para você do que seguir algum padrão.